# Removing Parts of String With Sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed

I have lines of data that looks like this:

```
sp_A0A342_ATPB_COFAR_6_+_contigs_full.fasta
sp_A0A342_ATPB_COFAR_9_-_contigs_full.fasta
sp_A0A373_RK16_COFAR_10_-_contigs_full.fasta
sp_A0A373_RK16_COFAR_8_+_contigs_full.fasta
sp_A0A4W3_SPEA_GEOSL_15_-_contigs_full.fasta
```

How can I use `sed` to delete parts of string after 4th column (_ separated) for each line.
Finally yielding:

```
sp_A0A342_ATPB_COFAR
sp_A0A342_ATPB_COFAR
sp_A0A373_RK16_COFAR
sp_A0A373_RK16_COFAR
sp_A0A4W3_SPEA_GEOSL
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`cut` is a better fit.

```
cut -d_ -f 1-4 old_file
```

This simply means use _ as delimiter, and keep fields 1-4.

If you insist on `sed`:

```
sed 's/\(_[^_]*\)\{4\}$//'
```

This left hand side matches exactly four repetitions of a group, consisting of an underscore followed by 0 or more non-underscores.  After that, we must be at the end of the line.  This is all replaced by nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e 's/\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_\([^_]*\)_.*/\1_\2_\3_\4' infile > outfile
```

Match "any number of not '_'", saving what was matched between \( and \), followed by '_'.  Do this 4 times, then match anything for the rest of the line (to be ignored).  Substitute with each of the matches separated by '_'.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possibility:

```
sed -E -e 's|^([^_]+(_[^_]+){3}).*$|\1|'
```

where -E, like -r in GNU sed, turns on extended regular expressions for readability.

Just because you *can* do it in sed, though, doesn't mean you *should*. I like cut much much better for this.

Answer (score 3):

AWK likes to play in the fields:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"}{print $1,$2,$3,$4}' inputfile
```

or, more generally:

```
awk -v count=4 'BEGIN{FS="_"}{for(i=1;i<=count;i++){printf "%s%s",sep,$i;sep=FS};printf "\n"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e 's/_[0-9][0-9]*_[+-]_contigs_full.fasta$//g'
```

Still the cut answer is probably faster and just generally better.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, cut is way better, and yes matching the back of each is easier.

I finally got a match using the beginning of each line:

```
 sed -r 's/(([^_]*_){3}([^_]*)).*/\1/' oldFile > newFile
```